# How to run flask on apache using mod_wsgi-express on same ip as a subdomain

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I want to run flask on apache.I have already installed mod_wsgi-express and my flask application is running on port 8000(localhost:8000) but i want to run my application as a subdomain i dont want to open a new port and want to run the application on same ip using '/'(ex- localhost/application).I have already drupal running on port 80.
So basically i want my drupal run on url(localhost) and flask app on url(localhost/flaskapp) .How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use your main Apache to run mod_wsgi as well, instead of mod_wsgi-express. Use mod_wsgi-express just for development.

Presuming you do not have mod_wsgi installed from a system package, you can run:

```
sudo mod_wsgi-express install-module
```

and it will copy the mod_wsgi module into your Apache configuration. The command will also output two lines that you need to include in your main Apache configuration to have it load mod_wsgi and set the correct location for your Python installation or virtual environment.

You should then configure your main Apache installation manually to have it also host your Flask application using mod_wsgi. See the Flask documentation on mod_wsgi for details, but because you still want to run a PHP application, also read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html

Because where you put configuration for Apache depends on the Linux distribution used, can't tell you exactly where you need to put stuff and what steps you may need to do to enable it.

Comment: quick question @Graham. Does that mean mod_wsgi-express is most suited for a development environment? (For example, if we have nginx reverse proxying to Apache for a Django app, that app should not ideally be serving through mod_wsgi-express but through mod_wsgi, yeah?)

Comment: Not at all. I would argue that mod_wsgi-express is likely to have a better configuration for hosting a Python web application than if you had configured Apache/mod_wsgi itself. It is after all still using Apache and normal mod_wsgi, it is just that I generate a configuration which based on my experience and being the author, is going to make things work much better than what most people have. The way it is setup means that in most cases you wouldn't even need nginx in front as that wouldn't add much benefit.

Comment: That mod_wsgi-express alone is more than adequate, and because it has in some respect been purpose built for it as well, making it a better solution than others available, it is especially good for running WSGI applications inside containers using runtimes such as Docker.